# Running commands in a terminal via exec in Java NOT as root

Tags: java, exec, runtime.exec

I've been playing around with exec and although it opens a terminal with the user being me, it doesn't seem to be able to execute commands I give it =/ code is as follows:

```
try{
  Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
  Process proc = rt.exec("xterm -e \"source /home/USER/.bashrc; ~/./myscript.sh\"")
}
catch(Throwable t)
  t.printStackTrace();
```

In the xterm console I get:

```
xterm: Can't execvp ": No such file or directory
user@user:$
```

Which is then a terminal waiting to be used, and will not go away until I ctrl-d it.

Not sure what's going on here?...

Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you take out your custom script from the call, and just source your .bashrc file?  If that works, it's probably something in your script that's causing the issue.

Comment: This is likely a path problem.  Try specifying the full path to xterm.

Comment: Hi, specifying the full path to xterm didn't help, I have the same message, only with 'usr/bin/xterm: Can't...etc' instead of just 'xterm: Can't....etc'

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can pass shell stuff into xterm's `-e` option. It wants a program and optional parameters for that program. `source` is a shell built-in.

Something you can try doing is just calling your `myscript.sh` and modifying it so that it sources your bashrc at the top. Or create a new bash script that sources your rc file then runs `myscript.sh`.